# Transitivity on relations

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I have a question concerning proving properties of Relations. 
The question is this: 
How would I go about proving that, if R and S (R and S both being different Relations) are transitive, then R union S is transitive?

The answer is actually FALSE, and then a counter example is given as a solution in the book.

I understand how the counterexample works as explained in the book, but what I don't understand is, how exactly they arrive to the conclusion that the statement is actually false.

Basically I can see myself giving a proof that if that for all values (x,y,z) in R and S, if (x,y) is in R and (y,z) is in R, (x, z) is in R since R is transitive. And if (x,y) is in S and (y,z) is in S, (x,z) is in S since S is transitive. Since (x,z) is in both R and S, the intersection is true. But why wouldn't the union of R and S be true as well?

Is it because that the proof cannot be ended with "since (x,z) is in both R and S, (x,z) can be in R or S"? Basically, that a proof can't be ended with an OR statement at the end?

Comment: While I find this type of question interesting, it's off-topic for this site. It belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/. BTW, here's a hint: you're talking about the **union**, not the **intersection**.

Comment: I guess since this hasn't been closed, the community disagrees that it's off-topic. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand how the counterexample works as explained in the book, but what I don't understand is, how exactly they arrive to the conclusion that the statement is actually false.

Given that there's a (presumably valid) counterexample, the statement **has** to be false. Trying to apply your proof to the counterexample can help reveal the error.

That's not to say that it's *never* the case that the union of two transitive relations is itself transitive. Indeed, there are obvious examples such as the union of a transitive relation with itself or the union of `less-than` and `less-than-or-equal-to` (which is equal to `less-than-or-equal-to` for any reasonable definition). But the original statement asserts that this is the case for **any** two transitive relations. A single counterexample disproves it. If you could provide a (valid) proof of the statement, you'd have discovered a paradox. This usually causes mathematicians to reevaluate the system's axioms to remove the paradox. In this case there is no paradox.

Let `T` be the union of `R` and `S` (for the sake of simplicity, let's assume domain equals range and that it's the same set for both). What you are trying to prove is that if `xTy` and `yTz`, then it must be the case that `xTz`. As part of your proof outline, you state the following:

> if (x,y) is in R and (y,z) is in R, (x, z) is in R since R is transitive

This is clearly true as it's just the definition of transitivity. As you point out, it can be used to prove the transitivity of the intersection of two transitive relations. However, since `T` is the *union*, there's no reason to assume that `xRy`; it might be that `xSy` only. Since you can't prove the antecedent (that `xRy` and `yRz`), the consequent (that `xRz`) is irrelevant. Similarly, you can't show that `xSz`. If you can't show that `xRz` or `xSz`, there's no reason to believe that `xTz`.

This implies the sort of situation that gives a counter example to the statement: when one half of the transitive pair comes only from `R` and the other comes only from `S`. As a simple, contrived, example, define the relations over the set `{1,2,3}`:

`R={(1,2)}`
`S={(2,3)}`

Clearly, both R and S are transitive (as there are no `x, y, z` such that `xRy and yRz` or `xSy and ySz`). On the other hand,

`T={(1,2),(2,3)}`

is not transitive. While `1T2` (since `1R2`) and `2T3` (since `2S3`), it is not the case that `1T3`. Your textbook probably gives a more natural counterexample, but I feel that this gives a good understanding of what can cause the assertion to fail.